# How to know if I completely exit nautilus as root

Tags: nautilus

I just use a "sudo nautilus" (yes, sudo not gksudo) command to delete a few directory which is owned by root. Then I hit close button to exit it.
So my question is:
How do I know that I am not using nautilus as root now (after I hit a close button)
How do I know that what permission I'm running nautilus so I dont accidentally make some unwanted change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look back in your terminal. If the last line is your prompt then for sure your last command linline, `sudo nautilus` in your case, has finished.

Comment: Hi Radu. Thank you for your answer. I had closed both of nautilus and terminal window at that time. So does restarting my system will make nautilus back to using as user (not root)?

Comment: @lthiano If you closed your terminal also, then for sure any command running in it was finished. So, you don't need any restart; when you will start your nautilus again as normal (let say from launcher) it will run under your permissions, and no way as root.

Comment: Thank you again. Now I know that closing terminal window will also close all "sudo" application in it.